# Does ASP.NET MVC denies use of client side MVVM?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js, client-side

Here i am coming from windows forms development.

I have my Business Layer DLLs and DALs and i want to create web apps based on these.

Started with standard ASP.NET MVC4 and everything looks good.

Now i want to make the user experience better and i thought that WEB API with knockoutJS would help me.

But as i am reading on various tutorials and books i begin to question this benefit.

**My target:** To AJAXify hence making user experience better.

**My current thoughts:**

1) Use knockoutJS and WEB Api in my existing MVC application

2) Just use jquery + WEB Api in my existing MVC application to do what i want.

I thought that #2 is old practice and i should move to #1 or similar.

But when i am start reading about viewmodels, routing e.t.c. i get confused because i wouldn't know where to create and manage these. In ASP.NET models or in Javascript or in both?

I "smell" spaghetti in my head ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, your models on the client side must match up with the models your are passing in from the server side.  Seems redundant?  Yes, but that is the nature of having a two-tier solution (server-side and client-side).

With that said, if you would like to make your code a little shorter on the client side and maybe save a little time, you can look at the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which automatically converts your json from the server into knockout observables.

Comment: So server-side MVC and client-side MVVM are not enemies as long as you keep logic in one place as possible. But it means that my class contracts will exist in two places but there is no way around this. correct?

Comment: Correct, they are certainly not enemies.  And if you are not using the ko.mapping plugin you will probably have to define your classes on the client side.  But the ko.mapping plugin will save you from having to define your classes on the client side because it just uses the structure of the JSON you pass from the server side.